# Sweet Alert Dialog library missing some class which causes error

Tags: android

I am using this library for sweetalert

```
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
```

I am getting this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name:
>   cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null

if anybody helps thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Basically this file name does not exist at the location you are looking for, you can download the jar of this library from github and then paste this jar in the libs folder of your project. Then add the dependency of the jar as:

compile files('libs/name-of-jar.jar')

and then rebuild the project and try! :)